Emacs top bar doesn't follow system theme in Fedora
I have dark theme enabled in Fedora (Gnome), but Emacs doesn't follow it. How to make it dark?
Emacs window:


If you're not able to do custom color preference edits, I was able to get the Emacs GUI (the GUI window/not the background of the terminal) to enter a dark mode using gnome-tweaks in Gnome.
On the Appearance tab, next to Legacy Applications, select Adwaita-dark. It seems that Emacs relies on this Legacy implementation and won't follow some theme selections, so you might need to find a route like this one. Adwaita-dark worked well and the GUI window updates immediately when it is selected from the Legacy Applications menu. I'd love to hear the explanation of why this works from someone more knowledgeable.
